# Dio error, disappears when web security is disabled

Tags: flutter, http, dart, http-headers, dio

So I need ASAP to do a request to the Google Places API using Dart for a flutter web app. I am using Dio I found some answers, which said that XMLHttpRequest Error would disappear if I added headers. I added the headers and the problem persists. I received some help from a Software Engineer (I'm a newbie), and although he was unfamiliar with Dio, he edited a file in the flutter SDK which disabled security with the flag `--disable---web-security`

```
path: C:\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\lib\src\web file: chrome.dart
(Here I only added the code block changed from the file)

final int port = debugPort ?? await _operatingSystemUtils.findFreePort();
final List<String> args = <String>[
  chromeExecutable,
  // Using a tmp directory ensures that a new instance of chrome launches
  // allowing for the remote debug port to be enabled.
  '--user-data-dir=${userDataDir.path}',
  '--remote-debugging-port=$port',
  // When the DevTools has focus we don't want to slow down the application.
  '--disable-background-timer-throttling',
  // Since we are using a temp profile, disable features that slow the
  // Chrome launch.
  '--disable-extensions',
  '--disable-popup-blocking',
  '--bwsi',
  '--no-first-run',
  '--no-default-browser-check',
  '--disable-default-apps',
  '--disable-translate',
  '--disable-web-security', //the line added
  if (headless) ...<String>[
    '--headless',
    '--disable-gpu',
    '--no-sandbox',
    '--window-size=2400,1800',
  ],
  url,
];
```

Once web security was disabled, Dio worked fine, with the API. The request is executed and returns with a 200 according to the DevTools console but then security blocks it off. So my question is what header am I missing, or what should I add to the Dio() object in order to re-activate web security and be able to make requests.

```
Dio request to Places API

try {
  var dio = Dio();
  dio.options.headers["Access-Control-Allow-Credentials"] = "true";
  dio.options.headers["Access-Control-Allow-Headers"] =
      "Origin,Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token,locale";
  dio.options.headers["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"] = "*";
  dio.options.headers["Access-Control-Allow-Methods"] =
      "GET, HEAD, POST, OPTIONS";

  dio.options.responseType = ResponseType.json;
  String url =
      autocompleteUrl(search, sessionToken, locale, components, placeType);
  //print(url);
  var response = await dio.get(url);

  var json = convert.jsonDecode(response.data);

  var jsonResults = json[_f.predictions] as List;

  return jsonResults.map((p) => PlaceSearch.fromMap(p)).toList(); //modeling the response
} on DioError catch (e) {
  return null;
}
```

Thank you for taking the time to help.

EDIT:

When I would print the error data this would show up

> request : null
> message : XMLHttpRequest error.
> DioError [DioErrorType.RESPONSE]: XMLHttpRequest error.
>
> Error in DevTools:
> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=a&key=keyg&sessionToken=e1f7496d-a62e-437d-877d-d93e5045e22d&language=null&components=country:us&types=address' from origin 'http://localhost:49234' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: Can you post the error?

Comment: I've been trying to enable the web security again to make the error show itself and honestly was unble to. However this is the error I had. https://github.com/flutterchina/dio/issues/750

Comment: Found the error, posted on edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same-origin policy causing the error only happens when the request is from client to server not from server to server. So I created a cloud function that makes the request and returns the response. Below is the function in typescript

```
import axios from "axios";

export const serverRequest = functions.https.onCall(async (url, context)=> {
  isAuthenticatedAdmin(context);
  const response = await axios.get(url as string).then(({data})=> data);
  return response;
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I used another method for this. Initially, I attempted to modify the Flutter files, but I faced issues with that approach. The solution that worked for me was to run only this command:

```
flutter run -d chrome --web-browser-flag "--disable-web-security"
```

And that's it! This should resolve the problem.

Comment: OP stated that they didn't want to disable web security.

Answer (score 0):

To run web in Chrome
1- Go to flutter\bin\cache and remove a file named: flutter_tools.stamp
2- Go to flutter\packages\flutter_tools\lib\src\web and open the file chrome.dart.
3- Find '--disable-extensions'
4- Add '--disable-web-security'
5- Add '--user-data-dir=~/Desktop/chromedata'